# Requirejs module callback

Tags: requirejs

I'm pretty stuck ATM with Requirejs. I can't access from my required file.

I let you my code and you'll see the problem:

**index.html**:

```
<script src="libs/jquery/requirejs.js"></script>
<script src="js/boot.js"></script>
<script src="home/init.js"></script>
```

**boot.js**:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'libs/jquery/jquery',
        home: 'home/home'   
    }
});

// my main module
define('common', [
    'jquery'
], function($){

  $('body').append('boot loaded ');

  return { }
});

// require the main module
require(['common']);
```

Here, it's OK.

**home.js**:

```
// simple object
var home = {
    syl: 88
}
```

**init.js**:

```
// home module
define('init_home', [
    'jquery',
    'home'
], function($, home){

  $('body').append('init loaded');

  return home;
});

require(['init_home'], function(home) {
  console.log(home.syl); // Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'syl' of undefined 
});
```

Check out the error.

How can I access to my home.js? What's the syntax please?

Any tip is appreciate.

Thank's, regards.

Comment: shouldn't 'home.js' return something so that RequireJS can init argument 'home' with it in 'init.js' ?

Comment: Ok Francois then how to write my home.js in order to return the home object?

Comment: i cannot do the test right now but it should be something like: "define(function() { var home={ syl:88 }; return home; });"

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, you have not set the base URL. Requirejs loads all files relative to the base URL.

I suggest you restructure you code path so that all your JS files reside in a common folder, like:

```
<script src="scripts/libs/requirejs.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/boot.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/home/init.js"></script>
```

As you see, now the base URL is the "scripts" folder. Add a property to "requirejs.config":

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "scripts",
    .....
    .....
});
```

Now requirejs knows the code has to be loaded from the path relative to scripts folder.

Read this [documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles) for further clarification.

Also, you can return an object by simply defining:

```
define("module_name", {
    name: "value"
});
```